# Jade. Loop through directory of files

Tags: javascript, pug

im working on a site where im using jade for the html. I have a folder which contains 20 ish .html-files.

How can I with jade create a loop that lists all these files on a single page? Eg: list the files names.

Currently I just have a simple for loop which obviously not works.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  li= array[i]
}
```

Comment: Do you use node.js or  javascript in a browser?

Comment: [iteration](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/)

Comment: @Troncador im using javascript in the browser. es6.

Comment: @user2952238 javascript in a browser can't make a list of the files of your local computer neither in the server. Maybe the server can return a json with the list of the files

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now i've got a problem.

Comment: are you using php?

Comment: Not at the moment no, but i guess i will have to.

Comment: also you can use node.js and use javascript in the server

Comment: that sounds lik a more modern approach. lets do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server (PHP or another language) you can have a URL that respond with a JSON with a list of your html files

Something like this:

http://some.org/listfiles.json

And return something like this:

```
[
  "file1.html",
  "file2.html",
  "file3.html",
  ...
]
```

Then in your Javascript  you use ajax to get the json and put it in a variable
(For example you can use the library Jquery to get the json http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ ).

Then in Jade you can iterate throw the list of files.

http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/